# LINQ Issue: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.Module' to type 'System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple lambda expression which runs fine as a UNIT test and also runs fine when I copy the code into the Main method of my application. However, when I run the same piece of code within a callback method (via JMS courier) I get the above error. Has anyone encountered this?

Example code failing:

```
Expression<Func<JupiterDividend, bool>> expr = v => true;
expr.Compile();  // This is what fails
```

Comment: (Edited to display code properly.)

Comment: Could you perhaps show some of the stack dump? Especially the bits around "Expression". Also; do you know if JMS does anything "fun" like on-the-fly type creation that might throw a spanner?

Answer (score 2):

You will normally get this sort of error when a ModuleBuilder has already been 'compiled', or a TypeBuilder has already been 'compiled'.

I would check where such things happen. Also, a stack trace may be handy in this case.

Answer (score -1):

There is a bug report [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=338242), not sure though if it is the same issue that you experience. Apparently this has been fixed in .NET 3.5 SP1.